# JPA Problems mapping relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a problem when I try to persist my model. An exception is thrown when creating the EntityManagerFactory:

> Blockquote
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ASD] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
>       at project.serealization.util.PersistentManager.createSession(PersistentManager.java:24)
>       at project.serealization.SerializationTest.testProject(SerializationTest.java:25)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   **Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in asd.entity_one for column ENTITY_TWO_ID. Found: double, expected: bigint**
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:284)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1116)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:349)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
>       ... 24 more

The code for the two entities is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne 
{
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = EntityTwo.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_TWO_ID")
private EntityTwo entityTwo;

... 
}


@Entity
public class EntityTwo
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ELEMENT_ID")
private Long element_id;

...
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my model?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the message is self-explaining: the column type doesn't match the type used at the Java level. If you want to sore a `Long`, use a `BIGINT` as column type.

**Update:** I tested your code with Hibernate as JPA provider and `ENTITYONE.ENTITY_TWO_ID` is generated as a `BIGINT` column. Maybe you generated your table and changed the Java type later without regenerating the physical model. My suggestion would be to drop the table and to try again.

Comment: I don't get it. The database is created by the provider, isn't it? I don't even know from where this "double" came.

Comment: @Rosen Well, it is created by the provider if you tell him to do so (but you didn't mention that your table was generated in your question). But I've updated my answer.