# How can I map double relationships JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need map at JPA something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ve1W.png]

How I can map two relationships between two "tables", one of them is primary key and one to one (newClient in advance) and in the other side, a one to many that aint PK?

I tried something like this but it fails.

```
public class Recommendation implements Serializable {
    @Id @OneToOne
    @Column(name="...")
    private Client newClient;
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name="...")
    private Client oldFella;
    @Column(name="...")
    private Boolean wasUsedToGenerateBond;

...

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Id @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_client1")
private Client newClient;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_client2")
private Client oldFella;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I got in the Class Client something like: `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "newClient")
 private Set<Recommendation> recommendations = new HashSet<Recommendation>();
 @ManyToOne
 private Client theGuyWhoRecommendsMeThis;`

Comment: Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory. `mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: uo.ri.model.Recommendation.newClient in uo.ri.model.Cliente.recommendations`

Comment: Just checking: do you have getters and setters for your fields? You should. Also, you can try applying your annotation to the public members (getters in your case).

Comment: I got getters and setters (except Id attrb, because I generate hash code and equals on them).

Comment: Try to move your annotations to getters, then.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to have multiple ManyToMany relationships between two entities. Each relationship would have its own join table. The default name of the join table may be the same, so you would need to specify the @JoinTable's name.

possible answer here

[JPA Problems mapping relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522000/jpa-problems-mapping-relationships)

more information

[Hibernate 4.2, bidirectional @OneToOne and @Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290341/hibernate-4-2-bidirectional-onetoone-and-id)